# MvvmCross: ArgumentNullException in OnCreate() at startup

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am getting an ArgumentNullException in the OnCreate() - method in the MainActivity of my Xamarin.Forms application.

```
[Activity(
    Label = "MvxForms.Droid", 
    Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
    Theme = "@style/AppTheme", 
    MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<MainViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // more Initialization
    }
}
```

I am using MvvmCross 6.0.1. The same exception occurs at SplashScreen.cs if I set this class as the MainLauncher to true. Since I cannot compile the MvvmCross sources I am not able to step into the code. Here is an extract of the output:

```
05-11 20:55:24.565 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross[0x7f990b88bb00] -> System.Core[0x7f98f7d0e680]: 7
05-11 20:55:24.631 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref Appetizer.Forms.Droid.Android[0x7f990b88b380] -> MvvmCross.Platform[0x7f98f8d8c280]: 2
05-11 20:55:24.632 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Forms[0x7f98f8d8c100] -> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f990b88bc00]: 2
05-11 20:55:24.632 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref Appetizer.App[0x7f990783d000] -> MvvmCross.Forms[0x7f98f8d8c100]: 3
05-11 20:55:24.632 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref Appetizer.Forms.Droid.Android[0x7f990b88b380] -> MvvmCross[0x7f990b88bb00]: 5
05-11 20:55:24.635 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f990b88bc00] -> mscorlib[0x7f991170f780]: 48
05-11 20:55:24.647 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f990b88bc00] -> Mono.Android[0x7f98f8db8e00]: 33
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): Searching for 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): Probing 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): Found as 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): Searching for 'monodroid_free'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): Probing 'monodroid_free'.
05-11 20:55:25.234 D/Mono    ( 9207): Found as 'monodroid_free'.
05-11 20:55:25.462 I/mono-stdout( 9207): 2018-05-11 08:55:25 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Primary start2018-05-11 08:55:25 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Primary start

05-11 20:55:25.472 I/mono-stdout( 9207): 2018-05-11 08:55:25 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: FirstChance start2018-05-11 08:55:25 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: FirstChance start
2018-05-11 08:55:25 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: PlatformServices start

05-11 20:55:25.474 I/mono-stdout( 9207): 2018-05-11 08:55:25 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: PlatformServices start
05-11 20:55:25.519 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0x7f990b88bc00] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0x7f990783df80]: 3
05-11 20:55:25.521 D/Mono    ( 9207): Assembly Ref addref MvvmCross.Forms[0x7f98f8d8c100] -> System.Core[0x7f98f7d0e680]: 8
Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Exception:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

05-11 20:55:32.393 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib64/liblog.so'.
05-11 20:55:32.393 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib64/liblog.so'.
05-11 20:55:32.393 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib64/liblog.so' ('/system/lib64/liblog.so').
05-11 20:55:32.393 D/Mono    ( 9207): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
05-11 20:55:32.393 D/Mono    ( 9207): Probing '__android_log_print'.
05-11 20:55:32.393 D/Mono    ( 9207): Found as '__android_log_print'.
05-11 20:55:32.403 I/MonoDroid( 9207): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
05-11 20:55:32.417 I/MonoDroid( 9207): System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
05-11 20:55:32.417 I/MonoDroid( 9207): Parameter name: source
05-11 20:55:32.417 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Boolean& found) [0x0000d] in <1ea41f79845a40618089713a1d9403c4>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.417 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00000] in <1ea41f79845a40618089713a1d9403c4>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxFormsAndroidSetup.get_FormsApplication () [0x00036] in <0afca477417f4241b92e240f7a530ede>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxFormsAndroidSetup.CreateViewPresenter () [0x00006] in <0afca477417f4241b92e240f7a530ede>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetup.get_Presenter () [0x00000] in <dcc1f804568a45a5accd2fb0ee5e5ebf>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetup.RegisterPresenter () [0x00000] in <dcc1f804568a45a5accd2fb0ee5e5ebf>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetup.InitializePlatformServices () [0x0000c] in <dcc1f804568a45a5accd2fb0ee5e5ebf>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.InitializePrimary () [0x00052] in <dcc1f804568a45a5accd2fb0ee5e5ebf>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.StartSetupInitialization () [0x0000a] in <dcc1f804568a45a5accd2fb0ee5e5ebf>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.EnsureInitialized () [0x00017] in <dcc1f804568a45a5accd2fb0ee5e5ebf>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0000c] in <0afca477417f4241b92e240f7a530ede>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at Appetizer.Forms.Droid.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00001] in D:\projekte\Appetizer\Appetizer.Forms.Droid\Appetizer.Forms.Droid.Android\MainActivity.cs:21 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <25661073a35344a89f215a4cf81af37c>:0 
05-11 20:55:32.418 I/MonoDroid( 9207):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.3ed40da6-9cc9-41f5-a36d-733d0d36a19c(intptr,intptr,intptr)
05-11 20:55:32.462 W/art     ( 9207): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable
05-11 20:55:32.473 D/Mono    ( 9207): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
05-11 20:55:32.473 D/Mono    ( 9207): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
05-11 20:55:32.473 D/Mono    ( 9207): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
05-11 20:55:32.473 D/Mono    ( 9207): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.

05-11 20:55:39.680 E/mono    ( 9207): 
05-11 20:55:39.680 E/mono    ( 9207): Unhandled Exception:
05-11 20:55:39.680 E/mono    ( 9207): System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47302 1

05-11 20:55:39.680 E/mono    ( 9207): Parameter name: source
05-11 20:55:39.680 E/mono    ( 9207):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.3ed40da6-9cc9-41f5-a36d-733d0d36a19c(intptr,intptr,intptr)
05-11 20:55:39.681 E/mono-rt ( 9207): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
05-11 20:55:39.681 E/mono-rt ( 9207): Parameter name: source
05-11 20:55:39.681 E/mono-rt ( 9207):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.3ed40da6-9cc9-41f5-a36d-733d0d36a19c(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: ---------------------------------
MvvmCross
---------------------------------

IMPORTANT: No nuget content files will be installed!

Files to change yourself in every platform project:

- Core
* Add App.cs

- All app platforms
* Add Setup.cs

- Android, iOS, tvOS, MacOS
* Add LinkerPleaseInclude.cs

- Android
* Extend MainActivity from MvxAppCompatActivity. ( MainActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity { } )
* Add SplashScreen.cs if you want a splashscreen

Comment: Did you do the above step?

Comment: @srimanreddy is right, the initialization of MvvmCross is different from version 6.x.  You should check this sample https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/TipCalc/TipCalc.Forms.Droid/MainActivity.cs